# For every letter in a string, print its ascii character representation

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, ascii

I am reading from a socket and trying to debug some of the messages which are coming in. Right now, I am trying to see if there is any "invisible" letters sneaking past my regex. I do the following in order to get the literal string values.

```
socket.on('data', function (data) {
  const message = data.toString('ascii');
  let characters = [];
  message.forEach((letter, i) => characters.push(message.charCodeAt(i)));
  console.log(characters);
});
```

The result looks like this:

```
[58, 13, 10, 26]
```

I want to get something more human readable without a (manual) look up of each letter on an ascii table. That is, the list would look more like this:

```
[':', '\r', '\n', 'ctrl-z']
// or
[':', 'carriage return', 'new line', 'substitution']
```

Is there any way of accomplishing this with Node.js?

Comment: You can try `JSON.stringify(letter)`

Comment: But no, you really will need an ascii table

Comment: It seems to work for the most part, it is showing `\r` and `\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In node 5.1, you can just split the string into an array of characters and console.log the array. The built in console.log will print escape codes for non printing characters:

```
socket.on('data', function(data){
    const message = data.toString('ascii');
    console.log(message.split(''))
})
```

If you are using a lower version of node, you can use the [util](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html) package in node to get a string literal representation of your character.

Something like this should work:

```
socket.on('data', function(data){
    const message = data.toString('ascii');
    console.log(message.split('').map(function(c){
        return require('util').inspect(c);
    }))
})
```

Comment: Why `const`, not `var`? Is there a real reason?

Comment: OP used const, so I used const.

Comment: =) That's a pretty good reason. I didn't notice, as usual. Scusi

Comment: I used it because it doesn't really ever change so I heard that using `const` optimizes variables which will not be changed

Comment: When I first checked out const, I figured that it would help the JIT optimize generated instructions, but I've had mixed results: I've had the same code run slower when I swapped a var for a const. As always, there is no substitute for profiling. I like const because at the very least its a signpost to people reading the code.

Answer (score 0):

Use `message.charAt(i)` instead of `charCodeAt`.

Comment: Doesn't show the literal `\r` or `\n` characters in console

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Comment: That won't work at all. It will just return the character from the string.